# boilerplate free projection of case class to change data type of enum

Tags: scala, apache-spark, projection, case-class, enumeratum

I have an Enumeratum enum and need to load it into a spark data frame. Obviously, this fails due to a missing encoder.

```
import enumeratum._
sealed trait Foo extends EnumEntry

object Foo extends Enum[Foo] {

  val values = findValues

  case object Baz extends Foo
  case object Bar extends Foo
}
case class FooBar(a:Int, lotOfOthterFields:String, xxxx:Seq[Foo])
Seq(FooBar(1, "one", Foo.Baz), FooBar(2, "two", Foo.Bar)).toDF
```

Fails with `No Encoder found for type Foo`.
How can I project the case class (without boilerplate) to:

- either have it work fine in spark (I do **not**) want to have binary kryo output
- or convert it to a string via `Foo.Baz.entryName`(but without boile of defining a similar class) something along the lines of `Seq(FooBar(1, "one", Foo.Baz), FooBar(2, "two", Foo.Bar)).map(allValluesButxxxx, xxxx.entryName)`

Comment: So far I only could resort to applying the Enum`s entryName (String) but this is suboptimal.

Comment: I'd love to figure this out too; this doesn't let you use enumeratum, but at least serializes correctly: http://monkeythinkmonkeycode.com/eums-in-spark-datasets/